# How to fit layout in 2 devices with same DPI (320dpi) and different resolutions

Tags: android-layout, layout, resolution

I made a simple layout after reading Android documentation. My problem is the following : I have 2 devices with same DPI ( 320dpi ) and different resolutions, 1200x1920 and 800x1280. I would fit my layout so that it will be good in both devices.

Screenshots :

1200x1920 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxXf9.png

800x1200  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m80D8.png

If it could help I used dpi buckets;  120dpi,160dpi etc..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean of be good?
In my opinion, use dp instead of px. Then the text **size** on both screens will be the same.
e.g.

```
android:textSize="10dp"
```

If you mean that you want the count of letters in a line on both screens are the same:
I think you can use

```
int w=rootView.getWidth();
yourTextView.setTextSize(w/10.0);
```

And you may change the 10.0 to a regular scale.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean that the square is too small for the first device, in the second it looks great because it has to take up almost completely the screen. I would keep the proportions, I want remove the blank space after my text by increasing the square dimensions and text. I used dp for every size

Comment: You can set the image `width="match_parent"` and add margins. For the text I would reccomend using default sizes with `textAppearance` for example `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"`